# sudo (cd /some/dir; ./runscript.sh) fails

Tags: bash, sudo

So, in bash, this works fine:

`(cd /some/dir; ./runscript.sh)`

assuming /some/dir/runscript.sh exists.

but

```
sudo (cd /some/dir; ./runscript.sh)
```

fails with the error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `cd'
```

why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to give it as a command to `bash` as `()` is interpreted by `bash` to run the commands inside parentheses in a subshell:

```
sudo bash -c '(cd /some/dir; ./runscript.sh)'
```

Comment: I was aware of this syntax but still find the question interesting.  So, `(` is part of `bash` syntax, rather than being a command that `sudo` can receive—is that the exact problem?

Comment: @Wildcard exactly..

Answer (score 6):

At a lower level, `sudo` is not running the command(s) in bash (or other shell), but is actually starting a new process based on the "command" you pass it and starting that process with the remaining arguments you pass.

As @heemayl pointed out, you can use the syntax `sudo bash -c '(cd /some/dir; ./runscript.sh)'`. This is because `bash` is a legitimate system executable. `sudo` is unable to create a process named `(cd` as `(` is part of bash syntax, and typically not a valid executable name.

Comment: Of course, using the parentheses inside the `sh -c` is kinda pointless, as it gives you a subshell inside a sub process for no apparent reason.

Comment: Agreed, it's pointless overhead but makes for a simpler explanation.